# What is the 3rd parameter of Transition?

Tags: css

I have a bootstrap carousel which works well on every device except Ipads.

I am still researching and not ready to put out a full question but I came across CSS which I don't understand.

```
transition: 0.4s ease-in-out left;
```

works

```
transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
```

Creates an additional swipe of a white box object.

So what does the left represent in the transition styling?

Answer (score 2):

From CSS Tricks:

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/

```
.example {
    transition: [transition-property] [transition-duration] [transition-timing-function] [transition-delay];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it should be:

```
transition: left 0.4s ease-in-out;
```

When using the shorthand version, the property to be transitioned should be the first argument.

```
transition: "property" || "duration" || "timing-function" || "delay"
```

Ref: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#transition-shorthand-property